# Comparing a column from an array to a string or a numpy array to a string in python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I'm coding in python. Honestly I don't know if I need a simple array or a numpy array, I tried both and neither worked.

I started by importing numpy :

```
import numpy as np
```

I am creating a bot on discord and I want him to answer me if some conditions are met. for example when I call him with "confucius ?" the bot answers "yes ?"

I created an array in which I stock the message.content of all users (including the bot). So with the previous content I have

`stock_answer = ['confucius ?','yes ?']`

I also created a matrix where I stock, for each pre-determined question a list of answers :

```
answers = np.array([ 
    ['how are you ?', [
                       'fine',
                       'not fine',
                       'so-so',
    ]],
    ['are you hungry ?', [
                       'yes',
                       'no',
                       'maybe',
    ]]
], dtype=object)
```

Here's the code I came up with :

```
    stock_answer.append(message.content.lower())
    count = -1
    
    if len(stock_answer) == 20 :
        stock_answer.clear()
    if count in range(-1, -17, -2) :  #modified from range(-1, -17, 2) to range(-1, -17, -2) so the step of two goes from -1 to -3
        for i in answers[:,0] :
            if stock_answer[-1] == i :
                if 'confucius' in stock_answer[count - 2] :
                    await message.channel.send('yep')
                    count -= 2
```

I'm looking from the last element added in stock_answer and comparing it to my first column in my array. if it matches then I check if the bot was mentioned just before (so [-3]), and if it was then I want to reply.
by adding to the count I want to be able to reach further in stock_answer if the conversation continues. I added a `clear()` to clear the array and not have too much data.

After changing the code from `if count == range(-1, -17, -2) :` to `if count in range(-1, -17, -2) :` my loop works once. however it doesn't work the second time. eventhough now `count = -3` it doesn't go back into the array to check if the new string matches.

For now I simply want it to answer 'yep' to everything. I'll work on the rest after.
I printed a few elements to see what happens and I don't understand what doesn't work :

```
    print('stock_answer : ' + stock_answer[-1])
    print('count : ' + str(count))
    print('length : ' + str(len(stock_answer)))
    print('replies : ' + str(answers[:,0]))
```

If `stock_answer = ['confucius ?','yes ?', 'how are you ?']` I get this in my results :

stock_answer : how are you ?
count : -1
length : 3
answers : ['how are you ?' 'are you hungry ?']

So in theory the right elements are selected and I shoud be able to use them.
Thank you for all the help you could bring me !

Comment: What should `count == range(-1, -17, 2)` accomplish?
`range` is a sequence type (like list and tuples), not a number. Also -1 + 2 = 1, you can't go upwards from -1 to -17. 
Did you mean something like `count in range(-1, -17, -2)`?

Comment: @Sowasvonbot aaaaah ! I thought that when I specify the step I just have to say that we move two steps at a time. So the range is used to have a number between -1 and -17 as a condition with a step of two : -1, -3, -5... that's because I'm intersted in the contents of the array that are in array[-1], array[-3], ...
so does ```count == range(-1, -17, -2)``` mean "count is an odd number number   between -1 and -17" or did I understand this wrong ?

Comment: `count == range(-1, -17, -2)` checks, if both sides are the same. But `count` is a number and the other thing is a `range`-Object, so this can't be true.
Again, what you need is `in` instead of `==`. Then you have the odd numbers from `-1` to `-17`

Comment: @Sowasvonbot sorry for the late reply. you were right ! the first loop works with `in` however I can't repeat it a second time. the count goes to -3 but it won't anwer even if I write "how are you ?" again